# incrementing values using loops

Tags: php

I have 2 variables that have values of `1` and `0.5`.
I have a total of `200`, that i want to have a loop through the 2 variables increasing them by there own values and then stopping when they hit `200`

Could this be done in a `for loop`

I initially looked into using a for loop using:

```
for($i=$var1;$i<=$total;$i++)
{

}
```

This worked ok for 1 of the variables.

Thanks

Comment: Yes its possible, Are you having any issues ? have you tried implementing it ?

Comment: Yes you can, but you first have to be level 80 in order to do all this epic things ..

Comment: And the epic `foreach` requires level 85 .. :|

Comment: @dbf i hate the boss at level `84` .. still trying to get to `85`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take close look at [`for` loop](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php), it supports syntax like this:

```php
for ($i = 1, $j = 0; $i <= 10; $j += $i, print $i, $i++);
```

So you basically can do this:

```php
for( $i = 1, $j = 0.5; $i < 200; $i++, $j += 0.5){
    // Do stuff
}
```

Although I think this may confuse some people and it'll be more readable to write it this way:

```php
$j = 0;
for( $i = 0; $i < 200; $i++){
    // do stuff

    $j += 0;
}
```

Or you could also calculate `$j` in each step:

```php
$j = $i/2; // Before do stuff block
```

But I think this will have worse performance then just incrementing it;

Comment: How do I make it though, that in the loop if `var1 + var2 = 200` then stop the loop?

Comment: @sipher_z are you serious? `for( $i = 1, $j = 0.5; ($i+$j) < 200; $i++, $j += 0.5){`

Answer (score 1):

They are some [know issues](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54994) working with increment in `float`  here is a [live example](http://3v4l.org/F5XVD#v4310) that shows `Output for 4.3.10 - 4.4.9, 5.0.2 - 5.5.0beta2` affected

You can use `printf` to partially fix this or simple convert to integer then back to float

```
$var = 0.5;
for($i = 0; $i < 200; $i += $var) {
     printf("%.1f\n", $i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is possible in programming

do this for $i = 1;

```
for ($i=1;$<=200;$i++);
```

and do this for $i = .5

```
for($i=.5; $i<=200;$i+.5);
```